# In Selenium how do I find the "Current" object

Tags: java, selenium

I would like for Selenium to navigate a menu via arrow keys--Starting with clicking the top menu item then pressing "DOWN", "DOWN", ...

The problem is that you have to always supply a specific element to send the "DOWN" to.

Is there any way to get the current element?

I tried:

```
by.xpath(".")
```

but it said that the expression was unrecognized or didn't return a proper object.

I expect I'm jsut missing some stupid trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know of a more straightforward way than accessing `document.activeElement`

[How do I test which element has the focus in Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138152/how-do-i-test-which-element-has-the-focus-in-selenium-rc)

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time trying to work out how to type in the currently active form element.

Answer (score 41):

In Selenium 2.0, if you are using `WebDriver` to drive the tests in the browser, you can use the [`WebDriver.TargetLocator`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) class to get the element in focus, in a window/frame:

```
WebDriver driver = ... // initialize the driver
WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

If no element is in focus, the active element would turn out to be the `body` of the document being displayed, which might be the case when you launch a new page, for instance. When you invoke methods like `click`, `sendKeys` etc. you'll find the `WebElement` returned by the above invocation will always represent the element in focus.

This was tested using `FirefoxDriver`, and I would suspect that the same would be true of other drivers, except for the `HtmlUnitDriver` and similar drivers that do not use a full-fledged browser under the hood.

Answer (score 26):

in python:

```
element = driver.switch_to.active_element
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: No additional context needed for me.

Comment: Official documentation: [selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver — Selenium 3.141 documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element_by_name#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby/Capybara:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element
```

Note that this returns a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` not a `Capybara::Node::Element`.