# Test if an element is focused using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm really surprised I can't find  references on the internet to testing for element focus using Selenium Webdriver.

I'm wanting to check when when a form submission is attempted with a mandatory field missed, focus is moved to the empty field. But I cannot see any way to do this using the WebDriver API.

I will be able to find the focused element using a [JavascriptExecutor](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?). But reading the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?) makes me think there must be some way to perform the check using the driver itself.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`driver.switchTo().activeElement()` will return the currently focused `WebElement`.  Equality is well defined for `WebElement`, so you can call `element.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement())`.

Calling the slightly misleading named `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` does not in fact switch focus, neither does `driver.findElement()`, so you do not need to `switchTo().defaultContent()` after; in fact, doing so would probably blur the current element.

Comment: I have a text field which id="widget_113_signup_username" . I want to verify whether the focus is on that field or not. I wrote the
following code to do this. If cursor is not present on it bb = false, otherwise bb= true. Am I right? Is my code OK?
boolean bb = driver.switchTo().activeElement().equals(driver.findElement(By.id("widget_113_signup_username")));

Answer (score 5):

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

returns the currently focused element.

Makes sure you switch back after using

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Also if nothing is focused the `body` of the document is returned.

Take a look at this question as well.

[In Selenium how do I find the "Current" object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491806/in-selenium-how-do-i-find-the-current-object)

Comment: The answer from Daniel says `switchTo().defaultContent()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the active element using selector 'dom=document.activeElement'. Then you can assert whether it's the element you want it to be focused or not.

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriver is supposed to change focus when you use `Driver.FindElement` calls.  So you're last element in the Driver context is active.

**NOTE:** This breaks for any elements injected dynamic (e.g. jQuery), so you'd need to go the script route then.

Answer (score -1):

@danielwagner-hall The `boolean bb = driver.switchTo().activeElement().equals(driver.findElement(By.id("widget_113_si‌​gnup_username")));` will always pass but it doesn't prove that the element is brought into focus if the element is out of view.

NB: Unable to comment as not enough reputation points.

One way of approaching this could be to use `webElement.getLocation().getX();` `getY()` methods and reference the coordinates on the page and verify its focus.