# How to check if a text is highlighted on the page using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

1> What does highlighted text means? 
  Suppose you browse any page , select any text on that page using mouse or some other means. Let say "[image: Hello]" , "Sign Up "text is highlighted. Please correct my understanding if its wrong.

2> I tried the below code to get CssValue of color and background-color.
Using the given code:

```
    driver.get("https://facebook.com");
    String textColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pageFooter']/div[3]/div/span")).getCssValue("color");
    String bkgColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pageFooter']/div[3]/div/span")).getCssValue("background-color");
    System.out.println("TextColor : " + textColor );
    System.out.println("Background Color : " + bkgColor);
```

output:-

```
TextColor : rgba(115, 115, 115, 1)
Background Color : transparent
```

*TextColor gives the color of text.

** For highlighting i am using Robot class to send Ctrl+A  , though its selecting entire page, but it should output some different value. In that case also it's giving the text color only as above output.

Please let me know if i am doing right or is my understanding about highlighted text is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do it with Selenium by itself, but you can do it executing javascript with Selenium. Js is pretty simple:

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

[image]

So just:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.getSelection().toString();");
```

PS will not work in <=IE8 (will provide how if you'll need)

Comment: Perfect using JS code i am getting the highlighted text .

Answer (score 3):

The CSS style of the element with the selected text would not change after you select it's text in the browser. What you can do is to get the [current "active" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491806/in-selenium-how-do-i-find-the-current-object) and see if it is the desired one:

```
WebElement desiredElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pageFooter']/div[3]/div/span"));
WebElement activeElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Comment: using the activeElement() functions i am too make out some difference in the color code. seems this is also a good option to check for highlighted text.