# How to find the highlighted text using selenium web driver in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Hello I have tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475414/how-to-check-if-a-text-is-highlighted-on-the-page-using-selenium).
It is working only if we select the text manually.

But my case is like, we have found the text using the text search.

[image]

Is it possible to find the selected text using selenium web driver??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by using **getCssValue** method available in WebElement.

Demo:

> WebElement branch = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//h3[contains(text(),'locator')]"));
>
> String background = branch.getCssValue("background");
>
> Assert.assertEquals(background, "We know the actual bg color");