# How to send keys to the element in focus?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In my tests I have a number of modals and dropdowns which open and automatically have focus set on their input boxes.

I have seen that it is possible to assert that an element is in focus. But is there any shortcut way to send keys to the element currently in focus? I'd like to be able to skip all the work of finding each element every time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `activeElement()` feature of selenium to access the currently focused element [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492253/1048479).

E.g.

```
// select the current page context's active element
browser.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys('Test')
```

Comment: This only worked for me without the first calls. (Selenium 3.141.0)

`browser.switchTo.activeElement.sendKeys('Test')`

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you may use "browser actions":

```
browser.actions().sendKeys('Test').perform();
```