# Getting active element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
elem = driver.switch_to_active_element()
elem.send_keys('a')
```

I want to send keys to a currently active element on the page, but I don't know how to get the active element from driver. I need it because there is no name, id, class etc. on that element. I've found code for Java, something for Python(written above), but there's no result.

Here's the page, and the object "" with no attrs. How to select it?

```
<div action-name="menu-holder" class="uiMenuButtonSelectionHolder">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="choiceMenuClose" action-name="choice-menu-close"></a>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="uiInlineBlock uiMenuHolder">
    <div>
       <input type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [java - In Selenium how do I find the "Current" object - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491806/in-selenium-how-do-i-find-the-current-object) (somehow there's a Python solution there too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the input tag through a css selector like below. Take a look at [this](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors) to get a better understanding about selectors

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.uiInlineBlock input')
elem.send_keys('a')
```

The selector can be read as find the `input tag, descendant to the div with class name _uiInlineBlock_`.

Hopefully, you don't have other divs with the same class, in which case you'll have to use `find_elements_by_css_selector` and from the list of elements returned, pick the element that you want to `send_keys` to.

Edit:

If the element is not visible, you can either go through the flow of making it visible or you can execute javascript to find and set the value

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div.uiInlineBlock input').setAttribute('value', 'a');")
```

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: Have added how to handle hidden elements in the answer

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I have another problem. After that, I need to send enter key on that object In order to send value, but as I mentioned I can't access it in python. Is there any way to send enter also via JS, or have you any idea how to press enter after setting value.

Comment: @RastkoJović That will need another answer  to explain. Take a look at this question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing)

Comment: If you're going with the native JS solution, the final step would be `document.querySelector('div.uiInlineBlock input').dispatchEvent(ev);` and if your page has jquery already loaded, then in the jquery solution `$('div.uiInlineBlock input').trigger(e);`

Answer (score 20):

I've been struggling with this myself until I came across [this link.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_active_element)

`switch_to_active_element()` has been deprecated and we should be using `switch_to.active_element`

So, it should be:

```
elem = driver.switch_to.active_element
```